# Superclass and subclass error

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I need to create a super class and subclass and then use the area and perimeter from the super class in the sub class, but I can't figure out how to. I am very new to java and programming, so I apologize for probably looking like an idiot.

From my super class:

```
public double getArea() {
    return width * height;
}

public double getPerimeter(){
    return 2 * (width + height);
}
```

From my sub class(equation my professor gave us to use):

```
public double getArea(){
    return 2 * super.area() + length * super.perimeter();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Rectangle1.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
    return super.area() + length * super.perimeter();
```

Comment: Everyone who is a Java freak right now, was a beginner like you, all okay, your question is okay and a good one too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your **super class** doesn't seem to have **area()** and **perimeter()** method.

```
    return 2 * super.area() + length * super.perimeter();
```

should be

```
    return 2 * super.getArea() + length * super.getPerimeter();
```

Read about [How Super works in java](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html&ei=pSKsUK_wD87J0AXx8oD4Bw&usg=AFQjCNG0LHEAZjfZEfzU1ptAlorqeq26aw&sig2=Bbahi8H6nP-KKbdjyTJebA)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return 2 * super.getArea() + length * super.getPerimeter();
```